# How to specify end of header line with read.table

Tags: r, import, header

I have ASCII files with data separated by `$` signs.

There are 23 columns in the data, the first row is of column names, but there is inconsistency between the line endings, which causes R to import the data improperly, by shift the data left-wise with respect to their columns.

Header line:

```
ISR$CASE$I_F_COD$FOLL_SEQ$IMAGE$EVENT_DT$MFR_DT$FDA_DT$REPT_COD$MFR_NUM$MFR_SNDR$AGE$AGE_COD$GNDR_COD$E_SUB$WT$WT_COD$REPT_DT$OCCP_COD$DEATH_DT$TO_MFR$CONFID$REPORTER_COUNTRY
```

which does not end with a `$` sign.

First row line:

```
7215577$8135839$I$$7215577-0$20101011$$20110104$DIR$$$67$YR$F$N$220$LBS$20110102$CN$$N$Y$UNITED STATES$
```

Which does end with a `$` sign.

My import command:

```
read.table(filename, header=TRUE, sep="$", comment.char="", header=TRUE, quote="")
```

My guess is that the inconsistency between the line endings causes R to think that the records have one column more than the header, thus making the first column as a row.names column, which is not correct. Adding the specification `row.names=NULL` does not fix the issue.

If I manually add a $ sign in the file the problem is solved, but this is infeasible as the issue occurs in hundreds of files. Is there a way to specify how to read the header line? Do I have any alternative?

Additional info: the headers change across different files, so I cannot set my own vector of column names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dummy test file:

```
cat("ISR$CASE$I_F_COD$FOLL_SEQ$IMAGE$EVENT_DT$MFR_DT$FDA_DT$REPT_COD$MFR_NUM$MFR_SNDR$AGE$AGE_COD$GNDR_COD$E_SUB$WT$WT_COD$REPT_DT$OCCP_COD$DEATH_DT$TO_MFR$CONFID$REPORTER_COUNTRY\n7215577$8135839$I$$7215577-0$20101011$$20110104$DIR$$$67$YR$F$N$220$LBS$20110102$CN$$N$Y$UNITED STATES$",
file="deleteme.txt",
"\n")
```

**Solution** using `gsub`:

First read the file as text and then edit its content:

```
file_path <- "deleteme.txt"
fh <- file(file_path)
file_content <- readLines(fh)
close(fh)
```

**Either** add a `$` at the end of header row:

```
file_content[1] <- paste0(file_content, "$")
```

**Or** remove `$` from the end of **all** rows:

```
file_content <- gsub("\\$$", "", file_content)
```

Then we write the fixed file back to disk:

```
cat(paste0(file_content, collapse="\n"), file=paste0("fixed_", file_path),  "\n")
```

Now we can read the file:

```
df <- read.table(paste0("fixed_", file_path), header=TRUE, sep="$", comment.char="", quote="", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

And get the desired structure:

```
str(df)


'data.frame':   1 obs. of  23 variables:
$ ISR             : int 7215577
$ CASE            : int 8135839
$ I_F_COD         : chr "I"
$ FOLL_SEQ        : logi NA
$ IMAGE           : chr "7215577-0"
$ EVENT_DT        : int 20101011
$ MFR_DT          : logi NA
$ FDA_DT          : int 20110104
$ REPT_COD        : chr "DIR"
$ MFR_NUM         : logi NA
$ MFR_SNDR        : logi NA
$ AGE             : int 67
$ AGE_COD         : chr "YR"
$ GNDR_COD        : logi FALSE
$ E_SUB           : chr "N"
$ WT              : int 220
$ WT_COD          : chr "LBS"
$ REPT_DT         : int 20110102
$ OCCP_COD        : chr "CN"
$ DEATH_DT        : logi NA
$ TO_MFR          : chr "N"
$ CONFID          : chr "Y"
$ REPORTER_COUNTRY: chr "UNITED STATES "
```

Comment: Thank you. I was curious whether there was directly a solution through read.table, rather than using another function such as gsub or paste, but I guess I have to do that.

Comment: There might be other solutions. But at least, this solution has the advantage that the fixed files have a 'normal' structure...